# ng-show on AngularJS alert

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am trying to display some alerts with AngularJS, see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ - alert section.
I want to modify the example to show only the alerts that have a "show" attribute set to true:

```
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'error', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.', show: true }, 
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.', show: false }
  ];
```

In the alert tag I have added `ng-show="alert.show"`, but it seems it does not display any alert.
You can find the code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qbv4A9u1SnQeJy9o81lK?p=preview.

What have I done wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `ng-repeat` and `ng-show` to a parent div.

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-show="alert.show">
    <alert type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  </div>
  <button class='btn' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

`ng-show` is a directive by itself which I am skeptical is not working in hand with `alert` directive from UI Bootstrap.

[Modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EVfoIc?p=preview)

Comment: Great. Had the same problem and wondered why it did not work.